AWS Lambda: filter Kinesis records by boolean attribute
I've got a Kinesis Data Stream with an attached lambda.
Records are JSON, like this:
{
  "int_attribute": 1,
  "boolean_attribute": true
}

I can successfully filter the stream by "int_attribute" but I cannot do that for "boolean_attribute" (and it works if I put integer values also there).
Here is my filter definition:
[
  {
    "Pattern": "{ \"data\": { \"int_attribute\": [ 1 ], \"boolean_attribute\": [ true ] }}"
  }
]

but it doesn't work.
Any hint?

Your filter definition has a typo (booelan_attribute), is that just a mistype when asking the question?

Yes, it was a typo, just in this question. Fixed, thanks!
